# ormlite on android fails to read boolean value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

Using OrmLite 4.48. on Android 4.x. And it fails to read boolean fields from an entity

```
public class Thing ... { 
...
...

    @DatabaseField
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

When this is read back:

```
List<Thing> things = DaoFactory.getInstance(getActivity()).getThingDao().queryForAll();
for(Thing thing : things) {
    Log.d(thing.getName(), "Is active: "+thing.isActive())
}
```

It fails `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "false"` is thrown
SQLite uses 0 and 1 (small int) for boolean values.

Is this a bug in OrmLite (http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/22/) has not been fixed after all? Or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
```

That failed in the exact same way

Has anyone else ran in to that?
Thanks